# Apple Developer Account Tax Forms South Africa

Tags: developer-program

I am in the process of creating my Apple Developer Account, as we are ready to submit our app to the App Store. I am from South Africa, and I need to know how do we address the tax forms which I'm not sure about?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you provide some info on a specific item/form that is blocking you? Also, please mention if you are enrolling as an individual or organization?